# Git how to use `set-url` of remote repository

Tags: git

I need to change the url for an remote repository, so I was looking at the docs at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote but when I do:

```
git remote set-url git@github.com:gitusername/repository.git
```

I get the message `usage: git remote set-url [--push] <name> <newurl> [<oldurl>]`

I do not really understand, should I type:

```
git remote set-url --push gitusername git@github.com:gitusername/repository.git
```

or what is `<name>` standing for? And should I include the old url?

**UPDATE**

So when I type:

```
git remote set-url --push origin git@github.com:gitusername/repository.git
```

And after that type `git remote -v`

I get this:

```
origin  git@github.com:oldusername/oldrepo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:gitusername/repository.git (push)
```

How can I change the fetch?

Comment: It should be name of repository i.e. origin/master

Comment: Don't use `--push` at all. If you've already used `--push`, you have now set separate fetch and push URLs. You can *delete* the separate push URL (`git remote set-url origin --delete --push`). Use `git remote set-url` *without* `--push` to set the fetch URL; if the push URL is not set, it automatically is the same as the fetch URL.

Comment: @torek Thanks alot! Exactly what I needed :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following command updates the URL for an existing remote, `origin`:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

The command above updates both the fetch and push URLs.

Using `--push` will only update the push URL:

```
git remote set-url --push origin git@github.com:usertwo/repotwo.git
git remote -v

origin  git@github.com:user/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:usertwo/repotwo.git (push)
```

After this point, there is now a separate entry in `.git/config`:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:user/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    pushurl = git@github.com:usertwo/repotwo.git
```

Because there are now two separate entries, using `set-url` without `--push` will only update fetch, instead of both:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:userthree/repothree.git
git remote -v 

origin  git@github.com:userthree/repothree.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:usertwo/repotwo.git (push)
```

If you want to go back to the original state, you can either delete the `pushurl` entry from `.git/config`, or use `set-url --delete --push`:

```
git remote set-url --delete --push origin git@github.com:usertwo/repotwo.git
```

After this, calling `set-url` without `--push` with now update both push and fetch URLs.

Answer (score 5):

This command is used to add a new remote:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git
```

This command is used to change the URL of an existing remote repository:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git
```

This command used will push your code to the master branch of the remote repository defined with the origin and -u let you point your current local branch to the remote master branch:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the name of the remote, eg. `origin`

The names are also visible when listing the remotes, so you could check your current name (probably also `origin`)

```
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/schacon/ticgit (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/schacon/ticgit (push)
```

And useful when using multiple remotes, e.g. the if you fork a GitHub repo, then you could have a remote to your fork online and the original repo (sometimes called "upstream" by convention)

Answer (score 0):

Name refers to the shorthand name for a remote repository. By default it's usually called 'origin'. So in your case the command would be

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:gitusername/repository.git
```

The optional `--push` option will set a push URL instead of the fetch url.

Comment: Ah ok, but how to check the (fetch) ?